# can't run dos MBR

Tags: dos, masm, mbr

guys.I read MBR from c disk to a memory such as 0:0200H,and then i debug it.however,when i arrive 
0:7c18H REPZ
0:7c19H MOVSB
i get a message 'CPU error:incorrect opcode.Killing process.'
i dont know how to deal with it.
any help will be appreciated.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

REPZ MOVSB is a string move operation typically.  Your MBR is likely looking to read a string it expects to be in memory causing it to fail.